# SSRS 2008 New Excel Tabs based on variable/parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a relatively simple SSRS report that outputs a small table based on a parameter result. So you select parameter value P5 it returns the P5 data, select P6 it returns the P6 data and so on.

What I’ve been asked for, and am not even sure if it is possible is for each P number to export to its own tab in an excel sheet. Now I know I can do this using either sub reports or separate tables with the relevant page break adding in and the P number adding in a filter.

What I would ideally like to do is make it variable. So that when a new P number is added the report automatically adds that P number to the excel file as a new sheet. Like below:

[image]

Comment: How is this export happening at the moment?  I know you can output a report to Excel, and if you create a list grouped on a field this field name can be used as the tab title.  Is this the sort of behaviour you require, or is the excel sheet form another source?

Comment: When the SSRS report is run it automatically exports to excel. I know how to split the tabs and name them, what I need it to do is create new ones automatically. So that if a new file gets loaded say P5 the report exports with that file as a new tab. Got a feeling I'm going to  have to create a new table or sub report each time though.

Comment: I think as long as you have a **page break** in between your data and it has some **grouping based on the P1, P2...** then it should work using the PageName.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are trying to do but not by limiting the report to the parameterised P-value (for example, running only the P6 data). What you need to do is return all the data for all the P-values and then add a grouping layer on the table for the P-value with page breaks on the group. The Excel renderer will then put the different P-values into their own worksheet.